# PHP echo out multiple column names & values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that can collect urls from my friends. As the user, you can create a "folder or category(ie column)" and thereafter put your links there.

For example, if you wanted to create a column called "GAMES" and put your `www.ign.com` link in it, you could. This way you can organize.

When its time to display the content to the user, i want to be able to show the column name AND all the column values.

Ive been using this which works (kinda):

```
$callDbData = "SELECT * FROM $users_table ";
$callDbDataDoIt = mysqli_query($c2d, $callDbData) or die ("could not pull data" . mysqli_error($c2d));


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($callDbDataDoIt)){ 
    foreach ($row as $fieldName => $value) { 
        echo "the field name is: <strong>" . $fieldName . "</strong> and the value is: " .$value.'<br />';
    }  
}
```

But the issue is that, since the column names are dynamic (to be created by the user as they see fit), i cant select it and place it with HTML/CSS directly which is why i made my SELECT statement like i did above: `$callDbData = "SELECT * FROM $users_table ";`

Also, each user will have their own column count.

*** --------- EDIT ----------***

Based on the above, and because the table column names are all dynamic, i cant call to them by name to organize them. I need a general way to call each column and their values. Essentially printing them One column & all values at a time.

As an example, currently i have a table on the db called "userTBL". This table is unique to the newly registered user. Inside of it I have 3 columns (also dynamically created) called

---

```
-unsorted links
-magazines
-news
```

---

Each column on the db has URLS inside them, as an example:

**EXAMPLE ONE:** //THIS IS HOW THE VALUES ARE ON THE DB

```
-UNSORTED LINKS (column name)
url1 (value)
url2 (value)
url3 (value)

-MAGAZINES(column name)
url1 (value)
url2 (value)
url3 (value)
url4 (value)
url5 (value)
url6 (value)

-GAMES(column name)
url1 (value)
url2 (value)
```

So how its shown above, is exactly how it should be on the page when loaded on the front end because essentially, this will fill out a vertical menu. I need it to go to column 1, print the column name and all its values. Then move onto column 2 etc...

With the code (*shown above the "edit" line*) that i have currently to bring out the results, it comes out like this:

**EXAMPLE TWO**

```
-UNSORTED LINKS (column name)
url1 (value)

-MAGAZINES (column name)
url1 (value)

-GAMES (column name)
url1 (value)


-UNSORTED LINKS (column name)
url2 (value)

-MAGAZINES (column name)
url2 (value)

-GAMES (column name)
url2 (value)


-UNSORTED LINKS (column name)
url3 (value)

-MAGAZINES (column name)
url3 (value)

-GAMES (column name)
  url3 (value)
```

Any ideas how i can achieve the results like in EXAMPLE ONE?
**Thank you** in advanced for any help.

Comment: do you mean you want Games to be the header and links 1 through 3 to be the values under the header?

Comment: Yes sir. Thats exactly what i mean. I know im missing something. Cant quite figure it out

Comment: Since each user will have a different amount of columns for their content/links. I need each column to show as a header, and that columns values under that header. Then to repeat as needed

Comment: How do you get output like EXAMPLE II with multiple links per a single column (GAMES) and then move on to the next column (NEWS) and have multiple rows - when I look at your code you are looping rows and then WITHIN rows you are looping columns... Can you clarify your code vs EXAMPLE II so they match up exactly?

Comment: It seems from your code that it should give `games link 1` and then `news link 1` and then `games link 2` and then `games link 2` and etc. Instead you say you are getting all games and then all news. Can you confirm that EXAMPLE II is what your code is actually outputting and that the code you are using is still what is reflected in the question here?

Comment: Howdy Peters. im editing the question now so i can be clearer.

Comment: ok done. Should be much clearer now

Answer (score 1):

It's a classic breaking report:

```
$prevname = null;
while ($row = fetch()) {
    if ($name != $prevname) {
        echo "$name";
        $prevname = $name;
    }
    echo "$link";
}
```

---

### Edit

OK, as I understand from the comments and edited question you are looking to change the sorting, iterating through rows within columns rather than columns within rows. Try something like this:

```
$a = array();
while ($row = fetch_assoc())
    $a[] = $row;
// now we have the whole set in memory in an array
$flds = array_keys($a[0]); // this gives the list of field names in array $flds
foreach ($flds as $f) { // loop through FIELDS in your OUTER loop
    echo "FIELD: $f<br />\n";
    foreach ($a as $row) // loop through ROWS in your INNER loop
        echo "DETAIL: $row[$f]<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: yea ... grouped results

Comment: Seems short enough but i dont fully understand it. Can you please do me a favor, and use the vars i have on mine so i can try to understand your flow (method of thinking). Sorry, im a noob. Unless its going to turn out like @hexerei softwares post below, because it produces the same results.

Comment: @somdow be a noob it is not important here but we provide solution for your problem, if you dont know how can it helps to you, probably you dont know where your problem is. Learn more about your code and we try help to you

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way of handling this using SQL.  (I generally find it's a lot easier to use SQL to manage the data and to use PHP to handle the output and interface)

Since you already have a users table that would work fine, however you might be able to manage this by creating a table called something like links, with foreign keys linking to the user.   On this table you could create a key (or column header) named `column_name` or something similar.   When users create add the link, they could either create a new column name, or choose an existing one they have created with a select menu.

Outputting the data would then be a lot easier.   You could have a query which does something like this (where user has an id:

```
$query = "select u.id, l.column_name, l.link
    from user u, link l
    where u.id = l.id
    and u.id = $user"
```

This would then generate something like this (like you had before)

```
GAMES link 1
GAMES link 2
GAMES link 3

NEWS link 1
NEWS link 2
NEWS link 3
```

However, since each of these items are named as different keys, you could generate the output in PHP and call the different rows in different ways like so.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
         echo '<h3>' .$row['column_name'] . '</h3>';
        foreach ($row['link] => $link) { 
            echo $link.'<br />';
        }  
    }
```

(note I did not test this, but the basic idea should work).

Answer (score 0):

typically you would achieve this by saving the last column name you echoed to skip repetitive outputs:

```
$lastFieldName = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($callDbDataDoIt)){ 
    foreach ($row as $fieldName => $value) {
        if ($fieldName != $lastFieldName) {
            echo "<strong>" . $fieldName . "</strong><br />";
            $lastFieldName = $fieldName;
        }
        echo '<a href="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a><br />';
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hello Hexerei, i tried this but it still separates each column. For example, if i have 2 columns(A&B), each with 5 values.  it should read: A (as the header), then Val1 through 5 under it. Then B(as theheader) and then Value 1 through 5 under that. I hope im clear. its hard to explain. Thanks in advanced

Comment: now i get it with your sample data above, actually still easy solution, i could post here, allow me one question though, will the number of columns be dynamic? is there a maximum of columns?